# Get text from the first element in a list that has a specific title with python/selenium

Tags: python, selenium

There is a list with 10 comments. Each comment has a title. The title has one xpath and the comment has another.

I want to check if the title "Weekly Report" exist in the list and then get the text from the corresponding comment, e.g. title 1 corresponds to comment 1, title 2 corresponds to comment 2 and so on. How can I code that? I'm stuck. I successfully can check if the list contains a title with Weekly Report, but don't know how to use that to get the corresponding Comment. Please help.

```
xpathCommentTitleList = [xpathCommentTitle1, xpathCommentTitle2, xpathCommentTitle3, xpathCommentTitle4, xpathCommentTitle5, xpathCommentTitle6, xpathCommentTitle7, xpathCommentTitle8, xpathCommentTitle9, xpathCommentTitle10]
xpathCommentList = [xpathComment1, xpathComment2, xpathComment3, xpathComment4, xpathComment5, xpathComment6, xpathComment7, xpathComment8, xpathComment9, xpathComment10]
        
    patternForFindingWeekTitle = r"Weekly Report"
    
    for xpath in xpathCommentTitleList: # loop through elements
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
        match2 = re.search(patternForFindingWeekTitle, element.text) 
        if match2:
            break
        else :
            print("Could not find any week title")
```

Comment: Please share the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as following:
Once the page is completed loading get all the comment titles and comment bodies.
Lets say comment title locator is `comment_title` and comment body locator is `comment body`.

```
titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(comment_title)
comments = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(comment_body)
for index, title in enumerate(titles, start=1):
    title_text = title.text
    if('Weekly Report' in title_text):
        return comments[index].text
```

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'` when I try this. Is that because sometimes the "Weekly Report" title/comment is not present on the page. Only on some users there is a "Weekly Report" title and comment.

Comment: I don't think so. Did you copy this code exactly? Also, I guess the the error appearing for the `title_text = title.text` line. Yes?